# Change GMSCircle radius with Animation

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google Maps iOS sdk for my app .In my app user can draw a fence(a circle) and later can edit to change and resize the radius of circle .
Its resizing properly but when radius value changes its instant,not a smooth animation like map zoom in/out.Is it achievable with latest GMaps sdk for ios?

Apparently, its not possible becuase what i see is GMSCircle is inherited from GMSOverlay which is child of NSObject,so its defineltly not a view,rather that overlay is drawn with some layer or something like that .

Any help is appreciated..!!

Thanks..!!

Comment: Have you tried changing the radius in an animation block? Maybe the setter changes some properties on the actual layer and this can be animated

Comment: Yes i tried changing it inside Animation block,its still not animating..

Comment: you could try using a timer to repeatedly update the radius from a starting value to and ending value...

Answer (score 2):

I found that you could just change the radius, and the circle changes.
So I wrote a helper class to do this:

```
@interface TAMapCircle : GMSCircle
{
    CLLocationDistance _from;
    CLLocationDistance _to;
    NSTimeInterval _duration;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^handler)();
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate * begin;
@end

@implementation TAMapCircle
// just call this
-(void)beginRadiusAnimationFrom:(CLLocationDistance)from
                             to:(CLLocationDistance)to
                       duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                completeHandler:(void(^)())completeHandler {

    self.handler = completeHandler;
    self.begin = [NSDate date];
    _from = from;
    _to = to;
    _duration = duration;

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateSelf) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

// internal update
-(void)updateSelf {

    NSTimeInterval i = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:_begin];
    if (i >= _duration) {
        self.radius = _to;
        self.handler();
        return;
    } else {
        CLLocationDistance d = (_to - _from) * i / _duration + _from;
        self.radius = d;
        // do it again at next run loop
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateSelf) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}
@end
```

Hopefully my answer can help.

Comment: do you have sample for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar using CADisplayLink. It makes it very easy to do simple animations in a GMSMapView.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the animation changes that you are attempting to make in `UIView` animation block. This has changed in the latest version of the iOS SDK such that the method signature is `[UIView beginAnimation:]`. Wrap any changes you make in this block and they will be animated by `UIKit`. If that doesn't work you can go to a lower level with `CoreAnimation` transactions.

Comment: Tried all that,but the problem is these all works for UIVIew ,and this overlay is NSObject Subclass..